# Telling Visual C++ to join several cpp file to make an unity build, to keep my code organized?

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010

I found many advantages to using an unity build (meaning having a single .cpp file with everything in it). I have many dependencies and global variables (that's a bad choice, but I want to stick with it, I don't want to explain why). My code is mangled, so each part often use another.

The biggest disadvantage of course being that editing code becomes fastidious.

My idea would be to split this big cpp files into many to make it more easy to manage the project.

So each time I rebuild, I'd like to know if I can join those files into one before it compiles. I asked about python, but maybe a .bat if it comes out easier than using python.

I use visual c++ express 2010 and I also use precompiled headers

Comment: At least leave a comment if you downvote...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why would you want to join the files into one? The linker will combine those object files into one executable for you. Read more about how compilation works.

Comment: Have you read http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds ? for a large project or when there are many dependencies, linking results in a lot of disk file seeking, which becomes very slow. C++ is like that. Read the article, unity builds actually improve build time by a non negligible factor.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, that seems something only relevant for extremely large projects.

Comment: The point of a makefile system is that you only rebuild the files you've changed. *That* is the normal way of reducing build times. The fact that one blogger has his own hack to avoid using makefiles does not make this a good idea.

Comment: what about linking ? linking also takes times, even if you recompile one source file. Or maybe maybe a makefile only relinks what is necessary ? @Jesse good : I use both Ogre3D and bullet physics, linking is long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UnityBuild.cpp:

```
#include "PartOneOfUglyCode.cpp"
#include "PartTwoOfUglyCode.cpp"
#include "PartThreeOfUglyCode.cpp"
...
```

Only compile UnityBuild.cpp.

I feel dirty. I'm glad you at least recognized that your code is poorly-designed.

Comment: I'd disagree with "just" an opinion, as different designs can help or hinder to development process. You've pretty much said yourself that the design is hindering your ability to manage the code.

Comment: C++ compiling can be slow, because C++ does not specify any method of building binary files, which is obviously its ugliest flaw. It's dirty, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want one file, you have one file, let us say, `main.cpp`. Inside `main.cpp` you can actually include your other parts like this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "part0.h"   
#include "part1.inc"
#iniclude "part2.cpp"

....

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the suffixes, `h`, `inc`, `cpp` do not matter.